# Windbg - PEB Paged Out (Virtual Page Size Confusion)

Tags: numbers, size, virtual, windbg

Can someone please explain to me what this means. (I've bolded the specific part in question).

The "Start VPN" field – in this case, `0x37D9BD30` – indicates the starting virtual page number. This must be converted to an actual address, by multiplying it by the page size. You can use the `?` (Evaluate Expression) command to **multiply this value by 0x2000, which is the page size for the Itanium-based machine the example comes from.**

```
kd> ? 37d9bd3e*2000        
Evaluate expression: 7676040298496 = 000006fb`37a7c000
```

Then the size of the range can be converted to bytes:

```
kd> ? 37d9bd3e-37d9bd30+1          <--   computes the number of pages
Evaluate expression: 15 = 00000000`0000000f
kd> ? f*2000
Evaluate expression: 122880 = 00000000`0001e000
```

So ExplorerFrame.dll starts at address `0x000006Fb37A7C000` and is `0x1E000` bytes large. You can load its symbols with:

```
kd> .reload /f ExplorerFrame.dll=6fb`37a7c000,1e000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page size depends on the processor. Calling [GetSystemInfo() [MSDN]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) gives you the page size in the field `SYSTEM_INFO.dwPageSize`. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_(computer_memory)#Windows-based_operating_systems) provides code that does it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(void) {
    SYSTEM_INFO si;
    GetSystemInfo(&si);

    printf("The page size for this system is %u bytes.\n", si.dwPageSize);

    return 0;
}
```

For the possible page sizes, refer to an Intel CPU manual.

- x86 CPUs may have 4k (most common), 2M (PAE supported) or 4M (no PAE support)
- x64 CPUs may have 4k (most common), 2M or even have 1G pages. It does not have 4M, since all x64 CPUs support PAE
- Itanium may have 4k, 8k, 64k, 256k, 1M, 4M, 16M or 256M pages